# Pprof profiler doesnt capture anything

Tags: go, debugging, profiling, goroutine, pprof

```
func main() {
    runtime.SetCPUProfileRate(500)
    cpuProfiler := "profile.prof"
    f, _ := os.Create(cpuProfiler)
    if err := pprof.StartCPUProfile(f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not start CPU profile: ", err)
    }
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    onKill := func(c chan os.Signal) {
        select {
        case <-c:
            defer f.Close()
            defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
            defer os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
    go onKill(c)
    streamCAN, streamIMU, done := mainfunctions.DialUpConnection(logger, configread.GetString("library.development.grpctarget"))
    rawCANData := mainfunctions.GetCANDataFromStream(logger, done, streamCAN)
    rawIMUData := mainfunctions.GetIMUDataFromStream(logger, done, streamIMU)
    moduleData := mainfunctions.DistributeDataFromStream(logger, done, rawCANData, rawIMUData)
    log.Debug(moduleData)
    mainfunctions.DistributeDataFromStream(logger, done, rawCANData, rawIMUData)
    channelOut := mainfunctions.RunAlgos(logger, done, moduleData)
    log.Debug(channelOut)
    mainfunctions.ReturnDataToStream(logger, done, channelOut)
    // subscribe to system signals
}
```

I have a go-app in which I have to compare the pprof output. For that purpose in the `main` function, I create a `cpuProfiler` and start it. I have a go routine that tracks signals for exit. After that I launch my `infinitely` running functions unless they are interrupted using using input(The app runs infinitely unless there is a key board interrupt). I let the app run for a while hoping to capture meta in the designated pprof file, but that file is always empty. Please do note that I do terminate the profiling by calling `stopCPUProfile`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. In the signal handling, we want to ensure that we stop the profiling before we quit. So we need not use `defer`.